# WPF : download files through CefSharp

Tags: wpf, download, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp 1 in my wpf app.
How can I download files from sites through my embedded navigator ? When I click on a download link, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

See answer in [this thread in the CefSharp group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true#!topic/cefsharp/bS8PhHRlSAc)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add a shceme handler for the 'file' protocol. That's what we did...

Register a scheme with CEF -

> ```
> CEF.RegisterScheme("file", new HandlerFactory());
> ```

Add a scheme handler that loads the file from disk and returns a relevant response